# asp.net control visibility using webmethod / jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

As I know, if you want to call a web-method by jQuery it must be a static method, but a static method doesn't have access to page controls/members.

So how to set visibility to a control using webmethod or jQuery ajax? I want to pass the value (true-false) to the server.

I don't want to use CSS (`display-visibility`) or jQuery `(selector).hide();` because anyone can change it using firebug.

Is that possible?

*I know there are tons of questions similar to mine but most of answers about using CSS and that's not what I want.*

Thank you and sorry for my horrible English :)

Comment: If you send somebody a letter on paper you can't stop that person from getting a pen and drawing on it. Similarly, anybody can activate the F12 developer tools on the browser and manually change what is being rendered. You can't stop that happening.

Comment: @AndrewShepherd totally i agree, but if the control visibility set to false from the server side then it  will not rendered in client side.. and that what i want..